# Golf Scoring SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following MS SQL query which cross references three tables, (tTeam, tPlayer and tScores) to get the total "Net score", "Gross score" and "Position" ordered by Net score and Team.

```
SELECT TeamID, Team, NetScore, Gross,  
CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN 'T' + CAST(rnk AS VARCHAR(5)) 
         ELSE CAST(rnk AS VARCHAR(5))
END Pos
FROM (
SELECT tTeam.TeamID, 
       tTeam.Title AS Team, 
       SUM(CONVERT(INT, tScores.Net_Score)) AS NetScore, 
       SUM(CONVERT(INT, tScores.Out_Score) + CONVERT(int, tScores.In_Score)) AS Gross, 
       rank() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM(CONVERT(INT, tScores.Net_Score))) rnk, 
       COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY SUM(CONVERT(INT, tScores.Net_Score))) cnt
FROM tScores INNER JOIN tPlayer ON tScores.PlayerID = tPlayer.PlayerID INNER JOIN tTeam ON tPlayer.TeamID = tTeam.TeamID 
WHERE tTeam.TournamentID = 13
GROUP BY tTeam.TeamID, tTeam.Title ) temp
ORDER BY NetScore, Team
```

The query works great but (and here is where i need some help), it is calculating all of the players Net and Gross scores by team when all I need it to do is calculate the "4 lowest Player's Net and Gross Scores" by team only.

I have spent the last day and a half pulling my hair out with this one and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you want to sum four lowest scores per player only, you might use another set of row_numbers to isolate lowest scores. I don't think that rn_gross is necessary (based on rank() function) but I included it nevertheless. If there is no need for separate numbering remove conditionals from sums and add `and lowestScores.rn_net <= 4` to where clause.

```
; with lowestScores as
(
  select *,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by PlayerID
                            order by CONVERT(INT, Net_Score)) rn_net,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by PlayerID
                            order by CONVERT(INT, Net_Score) + CONVERT(int,In_Score)) rn_gross
    from tScores                            
),
temp as
(
  SELECT tTeam.TeamID, 
         tTeam.Title AS Team, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN rn_net <= 4 THEN CONVERT(INT, lowestScores.Net_Score) END) AS NetScore, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN rn_gross <= 4 THEN CONVERT(INT, lowestScores.Out_Score) END
           + CASE WHEN rn_gross <= 4 THEN CONVERT(int, lowestScores.In_Score) END) AS Gross, 
         rank() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN rn_net <= 4 THEN CONVERT(INT, lowestScores.Net_Score) END)) rnk, 
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY SUM(CASE WHEN rn_net <= 4 THEN CONVERT(INT, lowestScores.Net_Score) END)) cnt
    FROM lowestScores 
   INNER JOIN tPlayer 
      ON lowestScores.PlayerID = tPlayer.PlayerID 
   INNER JOIN tTeam 
      ON tPlayer.TeamID = tTeam.TeamID 
   WHERE tTeam.TournamentID = 13
   GROUP BY tTeam.TeamID, tTeam.Title
)
SELECT TeamID, Team, NetScore, Gross,  
       CASE WHEN cnt > 1 
            THEN 'T' + CAST(rnk AS VARCHAR(5)) 
            ELSE CAST(rnk AS VARCHAR(5))
        END Pos
  FROM temp
 ORDER BY NetScore, Team
```